# Why does by repository Flow not update my viewModels livedata?

Tags: android, android-livedata

So currently I have a Dao with a function that emits a Flow<>

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${Constants.Redacted}")
    fun loadAllContacts(): Flow<List<Redacted>>
```

I am calling this from a repository like so

```
val loadAllContacts: Flow<List<Redacted>> = contactDao.loadAllContacts()
```

I am injecting the repository into the viewModel's constructor, and then at the top of my viewModel I have a val like so

```
val contacts: LiveData<List<Redacted>> = contactRepository.loadAllContacts.asLiveData()
```

Which is being observed in my Activity like so

```
viewModel.contacts.observe(this) { contacts ->
            viewModel.onContactsChange(contacts)
        }
```

My thinking is that the Flow is converted to a LiveData, and then I can observe this LiveData from my activity and kick off this function to actually update the viewModel upon the data being updated.

For now `onContactsChange` just looks like

```
fun onContactsChange(list: List<Redacted>) {
        Timber.i("VIEW UPDATE")
    }
```

The problem is that I only see this Timber log upon opening the activity, and never again. I verified that data IS going into my database, and I verified that an insert occurred successfully while the activity & viewModel are open. But I never see the log from `onContactsChange` again. When I close the activity, and reopen it, I do see my new data, so that is another reason I know my insert is working correctly.

I would like to add that I am using a single instance (singleton) of my repository, and I think I can verify this by the fact that I can see my data at all, at least when the view is first made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

Note: If your app runs in a single process, you should follow the singleton design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object. Each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances within a single process.
If your app runs in multiple processes, include `enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()` in your database builder invocation. That way, when you have an instance of AppDatabase in each process, you can invalidate the shared database file in one process, and this invalidation automatically propagates to the instances of AppDatabase within other processes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to follow your question, but I think I see the overall problem with your `Flow` object not updating the way you want it too.

Following [this quick tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-the-room-persistence-library-with-kotlin-flow-c73f461a0819), it seems that first you should declare your `Flow` object inside your Repository the same way you're already doing

```kt
val loadAllContacts: Flow<List<Redacted>> = contactDao.loadAllContacts()
```

and have your VM 'subscribe' to it by using the `collect` coroutine which would then allow you to dump all this data into a `MutableLiveData` State

```kt
data class YourState(..)

val state = MutableLiveData<YourState>()

init {
    contactRepository.loadAllContacts().collect {
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            state.postValue(YourState(
                ...
            )
        }
    }
}
```

that your Activity/Fragment could then observe for changes

```kt
viewModel.state.observe(.. { state ->
    // DO SOMETHING
})
```

P.S. The tutorial also mentions that because of how Dao's work, you might be getting updates for even the slightest of changes, but that you can use the `distinctUntilChanged()` `Flow` extension function to get more specific results.

Comment: I tried using collect earlier, that didn't actually work. I would like to worry about using something like distinctUntilChanged when I have the actual live updating part of this, but thank you!

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you try following the tutorial I provided?

Comment: Yes. So one thing I've not gathered is that it is inserting from a different context from where we are observing the data. I am using a singleton. object of the repository, but this seems to matter somehow. When I insert from my viewmodel, I see the updates no problem. Sorry for the delay in response.